# Printing the Source and Destination IP address from an ARP Packet

Tags: c, ip-address, libpcap, arp

I am able to print the destination and source address from an ARP packet. But I want to print the source ip and destination ip address from the ARP request. I have searched in the and found this structure.

```
`struct ether_arp {
    struct  arphdr ea_hdr;  
    u_char  arp_sha[6];
    u_char  arp_spa[4];
    u_char  arp_tha[6];
    u_char  arp_tpa[4];
};`
```

But when I am trying to print `arp_spa` I am getting something like `0:1:8:0`.
Obviously this is not the source IP address.

`arp_ptr = (struct ether_arp *) packet;`

I feel this is wrong as some bytes need to be skipped. But I am not sure about this

Can anybody please comment.

EDIT :

```
arp_ptr = (struct ether_arp *) packet;
            ptr = arp_ptr->arp_sha;
            i = ETHER_ADDR_LEN;
            printf(" source is:  ");
            do{ 

            printf("%s%x",(i == ETHER_ADDR_LEN) ? " " : ":",*ptr++);
            }while(--i>0);
```

The above is the code I am using to print either source IP or source MAC from ARP request

Comment: I have realised that I have to convert it to decimal. But while debugging with wireshark, I have seen that when printing the source MAC address from ARP request, I have seen that its printing the last 12 characters right but not the first four

Comment: For example, the source MAC address is `a0:d3:7a:5d:f7:37` but when using the `ether_arp` structure its printing `7a:5d:f7:37:8:6`

Comment: It sounds to me like your issue is related to struct packing — your compiler is inserting padding into the struct, offsetting every following field by two bytes. Try calculating the offset into your buffer by hand and printing the data directly, and see if you get the right data that way.